# Возвращается undefined, при попытке сравнить MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в поиске среднего арифметического . но тесты падают даже не проходя сравнение value1 и value2 подскажите тонкости работы с ними . ниже тесты .

```
function getAverage(value1, value2) {
    if (value1 + value2 == Infinity){
        if (value1>value2){
            return  (Number.MAX_VALUE - (Number.MAX_VALUE - (value2))/2); //(макс_число -(макс-2)/2)
        }else if(value1<value2){
            return (Number.MAX_VALUE - (Number.MAX_VALUE - (value1))/2); // (макс - (-макс/2)/2)
        }
    }else {
        return (value1 + value2)/2;
    }
}
```

Тесты

```
  it.optional('getAverage should return an average of two numbers', function() {
            assert.equal(5, tasks.getAverage(5, 5));
            assert.equal(5, tasks.getAverage(10, 0));
            assert.equal(0, tasks.getAverage(-3, 3));
            assert.equal(Number.MAX_VALUE-1, tasks.getAverage(Number.MAX_VALUE-2, Number.MAX_VALUE));
            assert.equal(Number.MAX_VALUE / 4, tasks.getAverage(Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE / 2));
        });
```

Comment: "в комментариях расшифровка формулы" - ??

Answer (score 2):

```js
function getAverage(value1, value2) {
  return value1 / 2 + value2 / 2;
}

console.log(getAverage(5, 5), 5);
console.log(getAverage(10, 0), 5);
console.log(getAverage(-3, 3), 0);
console.log(getAverage(Number.MAX_VALUE - 2, Number.MAX_VALUE), Number.MAX_VALUE - 1);
console.log(getAverage(Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE / 2), Number.MAX_VALUE / 4);
```

Comment: Хочешь битый тест? `3 * Number.MIN_VALUE` в каждый из аргументов :) Или даже просто `Number.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

JS использует double в качестве числового типа данных, а значит, в большинстве случаев его можно делить и умножать на 2 без потери точности. А вот складывать и вычитать - не всегда:

```js
console.log(2**53 - 2)
console.log(2**53 - 1)
console.log(2**53    )
console.log(2**53 + 1) // <<<
console.log(2**53 + 2)
```

Если алгоритм из вопроса верен, то он явно предполагает целочисленный тип с возможным переполнением, а не вещественный.

Скорее всего, надо что-то из этого (в зависимости от ожидаемых входных параметров):

```js
function avg1(a, b) {
  return (a + b) / 2
}

function avg2(a, b) {
  return a / 2 + b / 2
}

function avg3(a, b) {
  return a / 2 * 2 === a || b / 2 * 2 === b 
    ? a / 2 + b / 2
    : (a + b) / 2
}

for (var [a, b] of [
  [0, 0], [1, 10], [2**53, 1], [1, 2**53],
  [Number.MAX_VALUE, 1],
  [Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE],
  [Number.MIN_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE],
  [3 * Number.MIN_VALUE, 3 * Number.MIN_VALUE],
  [Number.MIN_VALUE, 3 * Number.MIN_VALUE],
]) {
  console.log(`${a} ${b} => ${avg1(a,b)} ${avg2(a,b)} ${avg3(a,b)}`)
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```